# Where can I view the history of a Deb package?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management

Can someone point me at either a utility or web page that lists the history of a particular `deb` package for a given distro?

Example:

Package in question: `g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf`
Distro: `Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial`

I can find [a page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf) that shows the package's direct dependencies and recommended packages, etc, but I am looking for a history of when this packages changed over time - say in the last year.

I would love to see when the most recent version was released and some record of changes (new releases, not source level changes) for a given package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Ubuntu, starting from [the link you give](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf), you can find [the package’s changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/gcc-defaults_1.150ubuntu1/changelog) by looking for the “Ubuntu Changelog” on the right-hand side. This doesn’t distinguish between releases; it will give you the full changelog for the version of the package currently in the suite you’re looking at. You can get an overview of the package in all currently-supported Ubuntu releases by going to [the package’s bug reports](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bugs) (“Bug Reports” link on the right-hand side), then clicking on [“Overview”](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults); scroll down to the “Package information” section:

[image: Screenshot of the <code>gcc-defaults</code> package information on Launchpad]

You’ll find similar information for Debian packages in the Debian package tracker, *e.g.* [here for `gcc-defaults`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gcc-defaults). The second entry in each “versioned links” line leads to the corresponding changelog.

[image: Screenshot of the <code>gcc-defaults</code> Debian package tracker]

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the history of changes through :

```
apt changelog <package_names>
```

or

```
apt-get changelog <package_name>
```